# pre_get_posts redirecting

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts, wp-redirect

Is there any possibility to redirect visitors to home page, for example, if they aren't allowed to view page's/post's content, using pre_get_posts action?

I'm trying to develop a simplified membership plugin and I want to test if current_user/ current_visitor is allowed to view the content of page/post. For that, I want to retrieve the queried post id from wp_query and test if user/visitor can view the content he asked for. If he can't, I want to redirect him to an error page.

I'm also using classes to encapsulate a little bit data.
Here's a piece of code:

```
class Public {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'try_redirect'));
    }

    private function try_redirect() {
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

If this isn't possible can you bring me another idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can allow only registered user to see your content by

1.this solution for post show only to login user

```
class RavsPublic {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'try_redirect'));
    }

    function try_redirect( $query ) {
        // not on home page and not login
        if( !is_home() && !is_user_logged_in() ){
            // send them to home page
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit();
            return $query;
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
new RavsPublic();
```

2)this solution if each post contain a user list ( as post meta ) which can see this post.

```
//show your content only to registered users
class RavsPublic {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'try_redirect'));
    }

    function try_redirect( $query ) {

        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        //current user login name
        $user = $current_user->user_login;

         $allowed_user_list = False;

        //if visiter visiting a post
        if( $query->query_vars->is_single ){

            //retrieve post
            $args=array(
                'name' => $query->query_vars->name,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 1
            );
            $my_posts = get_posts( $args );

            //retrieve post meta which contain allowed user list
            $allowed_user_list = get_post_meta( $my_posts[0]->ID, 'allowed_user_list');

            //check if user exist in allowed user list
            $is_user_allowed = in_array( $user, $allowed_user_list );
        }

        //redirect visiter to home page if he's not allowed to see this post or not login
        if( !is_home() && !is_user_logged_in() && !$is_user_allowed ){
            wp_redirect( home_url() ); // doesn't work
            exit();
            return $query;
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
new RavsPublic();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually want to `die();` after a redirect.  And, you can't put a redirect on EVERY page load, or it'll go into a redirect loop.

Try this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_109110');
function wpse_109110(){
    if (is_single()){
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        die();
    }
}
```

If you try to access a single post/page, it'll redirect to the home.

Answer (score 0):

[`public` is a reserved word in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php). You will get an error until you rename that, at least I do.

Secondly, nothing is going to happen until you instantiate that class or call your redirect method statically.

```
class My_Public {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'try_redirect'));
    }

    public function try_redirect() {
       wp_redirect( 'http://google.com' ); // doesn't work
       die;
    }
}
// This
// $mp = new My_Public();
// or this
add_action('pre_get_posts',array('My_Public','try_redirect'));
```

I would probably prefer `template_redirect` for this kind of redirect, rather than `pre_get_posts`. You have more information to work with for one, and you don't need the explicit `die;` with `template_redirect`, but the above does work.

There are other answers more directly addressing how to restrict users but I though I'd mention what I noticed and show you how to get your "test" code working.